# Does the Google Photos API support getting and setting tagged people on a photo

Tags: rest, google-photos-api

Can I get and manipulate people's face tagging using the Google Photos API?
I could not find this option on https://developers.google.com/photos...

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not part of their API.